# Css - counter por default que inicie en 5

Tags: css

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>
<h2>JavaScript Tutorial</h2>
<h2>Python Tutorial</h2>
<h2>SQL Tutorial</h2>
```

Como hacer que mi counter en lugar que inicie con el numero 1, inicie con el 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa `counter-set` en vez de `counter-reset`:

```css
body {
  counter-set: section 4;
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";  
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>
<h2>JavaScript Tutorial</h2>
<h2>Python Tutorial</h2>
<h2>SQL Tutorial</h2>
```

Comment: No necesita cambiar a counter-set la verdad, basta con darle el número. Recordar que el comportamiento de set es diferente a reset, por eso es preferible el reset.

Answer (score 2):

Solo basta pasarle el numero al `counter-reset`

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section 4;
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section " counter(section) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>
<h2>JavaScript Tutorial</h2>
<h2>Python Tutorial</h2>
<h2>SQL Tutorial</h2>
```